# Log-Structured-Merge tree key lookup complexity

Tags: tree, time-complexity, lookup

Im currently studying the Log-Structured-Merge tree described by O'Neil et. al. 
Something is not totally clear to me regarding the worst lookup complexity in an LSM tree. The components that reside on disk space store their data in a B-tree right?

As state from the paper:

> As  a  rule,  in  order  to  guarantee  that  all  entries  in  the 
>   LSM-tree  have been examined, it is necessary for an exact-match find
>   or range find to access each component (C_n)through  its  index 
>   structure.

This indicates to me that lookup through the Cn components residing in disk space worst case is O(n).

But that is only traversing over the components not traversing inside the component over the key-value pairs. Since the key-value pairs are stored in a B-tree which as O(log n) lookup complexity, does this mean that a lookup in a LSM tree is of complexity O(n log n)?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are mixing up number of components (lets call it M) and number of data points per component, lets call the maximum over all components N.

The complexity is then O(M*log(N)).

Often, the LSM tree has M=2, so the complexity of a lookup corresponds to the complexity of lookup in a single tree: O(log(N)).